# How to Declaring scalar table in sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to declare one element table so it can be used in future queries?

```
DECLARE @Emp TABLE
(
  ID BIGINT NULL,
  CompanyID BIGINT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @EMP
SELECT ID,CompanyID FROM Emp WHERE PIN = 123

SELECT COMPANYID FROM COMPANY WHERE ID = @Emp.CompanyID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not. A table per definition contains a (possibly) unlimited number of elements. However, you can always do something like this:

```
DECLARE @CompanyID BIGINT
SET @CompanyID = (SELECT TOP 1 CompanyID FROM @Emp WHERE ...)
```

By the way, the following line is not correct, as the `WHERE` clause is incomplete.

```
SELECT COMPANYID FROM COMPANY WHERE @Emp.CompanyID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intention is to create a table variable that will only store a maximum of one row, you can do it like this:

```
DECLARE @Emp TABLE
(
  ID BIGINT NULL,
  CompanyID BIGINT NULL,
  Lock char(1) not null default 'X' primary key check(Lock='X')
)

INSERT INTO @EMP (ID,CompanyID)
SELECT ID,CompanyID FROM Emp WHERE PIN = 123
```

Because the table's primary key is constrained to only one possible value, logically there can't be more than one row.